# How do multiple .. operators work in a for expression?

Tags: f#

I'm new to F# and I had trouble searching for the `..` operator. Can someone explain why this function works?

```
let oddsUnderN n = seq {for i in 1 .. 2 .. n -> i}
```

How do multiple `..` operators work?

Comment: [Loops: `for...in` Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233227.aspx)

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [sequence expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx) and is used to specify the starting value, increment and end value of the sequence. In this case the starting value is 1, end is n and increment is 2.

Comment: Increment is what I was missing. I'm used to seeing [1 .. 10]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the variable your assigning, `oddsUnderN` is a great clue as to what that loop will produce. That syntax allows you to skip every other element in the sequence, returning just the odd numbers.

So if n = 10 then your `i` would in turn equal:

```
1 3 5 7 9
```

So in the loop syntax of `for i in x .. y .. z do`:

- x is the starting value
- y is the incrementing value
- z is the final value

In other words. This expression

```
for i in 1 .. 10 do
```

...is shorthand for:

```
for i in 1 .. 1 .. 10 do
```